# creating a two-way table with totals in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I was wondering if there is an easy way to create a table that has the columns as well as row totals?

```
smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
    colnames(smoke) <- c("High","Low","Middle")
    rownames(smoke) <- c("current","former","never")
    smoke <- as.table(smoke)
```

I thought this would be super easy, but the solutions i found until now seem to be pretty complicated involving `lapply` and `rbind`. However, this seems as such a trivial task, there must be some easier way?

derired results:

```
> smoke
        High Low Middle TOTAL
current   51  43     22   116
former    92  28     21   141
never     68  22      9    99
TOTAL    211  93     52    51
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
addmargins(smoke)
```

`addmargins` is in the stats package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adorn_totals` from `janitor` :

```
library(janitor)
library(magrittr)

smoke %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  adorn_totals(name = 'TOTAL') %>%
  adorn_totals(name = 'TOTAL', where = 'col')

# rowname High Low Middle TOTAL
# current   51  43     22   116
#  former   92  28     21   141
#   never   68  22      9    99
#   TOTAL  211  93     52   356
```